# How to achieve normal/bump map on surface shader (Unity C#)?

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, shader, normals, cg

I have problems with the following CG surface shader. My goal is to have a NORMAL MAP used on the terrain the shader belongs to. When I apply the shader it doesn't throw any errors, but my terrain becomes black instead of having it's Main Texture and I cannot see any Normal Map effect on it. (check images attached). My question is: **How can I add a normal map on my custom (terrain) shader?**

```
Shader "Custom/Terrain" {
Properties {
// Zexture und Scale-Slot im Material erzeugen
    testTexture("Texture", 2D) = "white"{}
    testScale("Scale", Float) = 1
    _NormalMap ("Normal Map", 2D) = "bump" {}
}
SubShader {
    Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
    LOD 200

    // SHADER-Language = CG 

    CGPROGRAM
    // Physically based Standard lighting model, and enable shadows on all light types
    #pragma surface surf Standard fullforwardshadows

    // Use shader model 3.0 target, to get nicer looking lighting
    #pragma target 3.0

    const static int maxLayerCount = 8; // Max Amount of colors the terrain can have
    const static float epsilon = 1E-4; 

    int layerCount; 
    float3 baseColours[maxLayerCount]; 
    float baseStartHeights[maxLayerCount]; // ZONES FOR COLORS OF TERRAIN
    float baseBlends[maxLayerCount]; // BLENDS FoR COLORS/TEXTUREN
    float baseColourStrength[maxLayerCount];
    float baseTextureScales[maxLayerCount]; // Texture size
    float minHeight; //min. Hight of Map
    float maxHeight; //max. Hight of Map

    sampler2D testTexture; // Textur Slot
    float testScale; // Scale of the texture

    sampler2D _NormalMap;

    UNITY_DECLARE_TEX2DARRAY(baseTextures); // Texture-Array from TextureData(another Script) definieren

    struct Input {
        float3 worldPos; // Position on Map
        float3 worldNormal; // Normales of Map 
        float2 uv_Diffuse;
        INTERNAL_DATA
    };


    float inverseLerp(float a, float b, float value) // a = min.value, b = max.value, value = surrent value
    {  
       return saturate((value - a)/(b-a));
    }

    // --> TRIPLANAR MAPPING
    float3 triplanar (float3 worldPos, float scale, float3 blendAxes, int textureIndex)
    {
        float3 scaledWorldPos = worldPos/ scale;

        float3 xProjection = UNITY_SAMPLE_TEX2DARRAY(baseTextures, float3(scaledWorldPos.y,scaledWorldPos.z, textureIndex)) * blendAxes.x; 
        float3 yProjection = UNITY_SAMPLE_TEX2DARRAY(baseTextures, float3(scaledWorldPos.x,scaledWorldPos.z, textureIndex)) * blendAxes.y; 
        float3 zProjection = UNITY_SAMPLE_TEX2DARRAY(baseTextures, float3(scaledWorldPos.x,scaledWorldPos.y, textureIndex)) * blendAxes.z; 
        return xProjection + yProjection + zProjection; // Mix textures
    }

    // Add instancing support for this shader. You need to check 'Enable Instancing' on materials that use the shader.
    // See https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GPUInstancing.html for more information about instancing.
    // #pragma instancing_options assumeuniformscaling
    UNITY_INSTANCING_CBUFFER_START(Props)
        // put more per-instance properties here
    UNITY_INSTANCING_CBUFFER_END


    void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard o) {


    float heightPercent = inverseLerp(minHeight, maxHeight, IN.worldPos.y);

    float3 blendAxes = abs(IN.worldNormal); 
    blendAxes /= blendAxes.x + blendAxes.y + blendAxes.z;  

        for (int i = 0; i < layerCount; i++)
        {

            float drawStrenght = inverseLerp(-baseBlends[i]/2 - epsilon, baseBlends[i]/2, heightPercent - baseStartHeights[i]); 

            float3 baseColour = baseColours[i] * baseColourStrength[i]; 
            // Textur
            float3 textureColour = triplanar(IN.worldPos, baseTextureScales[i], blendAxes, i) * (1-baseColourStrength[i]);

            o.Albedo = o.Albedo * (1 - drawStrenght) + (baseColour + textureColour) * drawStrenght;
            o.Normal = UnpackNormal( tex2D(_NormalMap, IN.uv_Diffuse));
        }

    }
    ENDCG
}
FallBack "Diffuse"}
```

The image:
[image]

The material with texture in Unity Editor:

[image]

I am trying hard to understand CG but I also appreciate any help.
Credits to Sebastian Lague